# Button is not responding to click after applying all solutions android

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, onclicklistener

**activity_verify.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/countdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
     android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/otp"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:layout_below="@id/countdown"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:hint="Enter 4 digit OTP sent to your phone"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/verification"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/bttext"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/otp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Verify.java**

```
    package com.example.myapp.appfirst;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
.
.
.

public class Verify extends Activity{
    public Button bt;
    public EditText digits;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //App with fullscreen
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verification);
        digits = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.otp);
            getdata(); //This function sends otp to the phone and sets countdown timer for OTP verification
        Log.d("oncreate","Now going to buttonVerify()");
        buttonVerify();
    }

    public void buttonVerify() {
        Log.d("Button","Entered into buttonVerify");
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Button clicked","yaah!!");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"It's working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
.
.
.
}
       });
    }
.
.
.
```

The Logcat message "Button clicked/yaah!!" is never been shown and the toast message in onClick method is never displayed. The button do not click at all. 
I have gone through all the codes and questions on stackoverflow and I don't know what is wrong with my code whereas in other apps that I created the earlier, the same code was working perfectly.

Comment: does this log print or not         Log.d("Button","Entered into buttonVerify"); @sonubig909

Comment: @NileshRathod yes every log message except the log message inside the button's onclick method

Comment: just try one time put your code of click listener in oncreate() method

Comment: Toast.makeText(Verify.this, "It's working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: @NileshRathod My app is crashing now.

Comment: I assume that you want to place your EditText below your TextView. If that is the case change layout_below property of EditText from @id/ct to @id/countdown. Possibly your TextView is overlapping your button and preventing click(or maybe not)

Comment: @MilosLulic even Verify.this is not working. And the logcat is not showing the message for that inside the onclick method.

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi Edited. Sorry there is no any @id/ct. Sorry

Comment: @sonubig909 if you were using the same code in your app, try to click the button now. Possibly your button click was getting blocked by the TextView, however that should not be the case

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi Not clicking at all. I have updated the xml in the above question details.

Comment: @sonubig909 rather than setting an OnClickListener in code try using OnClick method in XML and if that doesn't work try examining your layout using tools -> android -> layout inspector

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi Mehul's code is working but, but only when I comment getdata() method. If I don't comment it, the button doesn't work. Here, getdata sends user credentials to the server using retrofit and then sets the texts like username, real name on the layout and then the another inner functions sends data to another php sms api on server for otp generation and sending. Now may you please tell me why it is not working?

Comment: @sonubig909 did you check your layout with layout inspector, if not please do. It will tell you exactly what's going on in your layout and use debugger to follow the flow of app in your code.

Comment: @AbhishekTyagi What should I see in the layout inspector? Regarding the button, isActivated is false where isClickable is true.

Comment: In layout inspector checkout if something is not overlapping your button at the time you are trying to click it. isActivated represents the state of the button whether it is pressed or not. So, it is correctly false in your case

Answer (score 1):

can you `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` above to line `setContentView(R.layout.test);`

See: http://prntscr.com/fn7zhe

your activity

```
public class Verify extends Activity {
    public Button bt;
    public EditText digits;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //App with fullscreen

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verification);
        digits = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.otp);
        //getdata(); //This function sends otp to the phone and sets countdown timer for OTP verification
        Log.d("oncreate", "Now going to buttonVerify()");
        buttonVerify();
    }

    public void buttonVerify() {
        Log.d("Button", "Entered into buttonVerify");
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Button clicked", "yaah!!");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "It's working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

See: layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/otp"
        style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:layout_below="@id/countdown"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:hint="Enter 4 digit OTP sent to your phone"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/verification"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="bttext"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/otp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not working :( The button doesn't click at all and nothing Toasts

Comment: what an issue I use same code which you gave in question. I just do change as above mentation. and its working sees screenshot.

Comment: Then why it is not working at all in my case? May you please give me the exact code by pasting it? Or I have other functions too in the oncreate method being called.

Comment: Your code is working but, but only when I comment getdata() method. If I don't comment it, the button doesn't work.
Here, getdata sends user credentials to the server using retrofit and then sets the texts like username, real name on the layout and then the another inner functions sends data to another php sms api on server for otp generation and sending.
Now may you please tell me why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Remove buttonVerify() method...
Use this ....

```
public class Verify extends Activity{
public Button bt;
public EditText digits;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_verify);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //App with fullscreen
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.verification);
    digits = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.otp);
        getdata(); //This function sends otp to the phone and sets countdown timer for OTP verification
    Log.d("oncreate","Now going to buttonVerify()");
     bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Button clicked","yaah!!");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"It's working",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }
                 });
}
```

Comment: Application crashes!